# Wrong number of histogram bins when specifying breaks as single number?

Tags: r

Why do the following two histograms have different numbers of bins?

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(10000)

length(hist(x, breaks = 20, plot = FALSE)$counts) # 18
length(hist(x, breaks = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 20+1), plot = FALSE)$counts) # 20
```

The manual of the histogram functions says about `breaks`:

> - a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram

So why doesn't the first option result in a histogram with 20 cells?

Comment: You didn't complete reading the manual. After that list of bullet points it says **In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; as the breakpoints will be set to pretty values...** where `pretty` is a function with its own documentation. See `?pretty` for details.

Answer (score 0):

The bins don’t correspond to exactly the number you put in, because of the way R runs its algorithm to break up the data but it gives you generally what you want. If you want more control over exactly the breakpoints between bins, you can be more precise with the breaks() option and give it a vector of breakpoints, like this:

`hist(mtcars, breaks=c(17,20,23,26,29,32), main=”Breaks is vector of breakpoints”)`

So you need to select the numbers of breaks, 17 to 20, then 20 to 34 etc so its 1 bin for 2 values.